# Fedora outputs junk to virtual ttys when I switch between them

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

On my Fedora 22 system, every time I switch between text terminals using Ctrl+Alt+Fx, the system outputs junk to the screen. It is usually something like:

```
[ 5385.916900] nouveau E [   PIBUS][0000:04:00.0] GPC0: 0x4188ac 0x00000001 (0x1970822e)
[ 5386.243255] nouveau E [   PIBUS][0000:04:00.0] HUB0: 0x6013d4 0xffffffff (0x1970822e)
```

How to turn this off completely?